# animate css on ios safari

Tags: jquery, ios, css, safari

I'm using the animate.css library (https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) which uses css keyframes.

It all works perfectly on desktop browsers, but on ios safari it won't animate at all, just skips to the last frame. Example is here:

https://liger.vm.bytemark.co.uk/animatetest/

Is this the same for anyone else on ios safari? I was very surprised to find no other mention of this after searching around, so maybe i'm doing something wrong.

The strange thing is that it works fine in ios safari IF the animated css class is added to an element with jquery after a click event of some kind, like:

```
$("#givebutton").click(function(){
    $("#givebutton").addClass('animated bounceOutDown');
});
```

i.e. when the animation is not happening on document ready or window load. I tried a workaround for the window load case, by adding a delay:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//same behaviour with: $(window).load(function(){

    window.setTimeout(function(){

        $("#givebutton").addClass('animated bounceInUp');

    }, 1000);

});
```

again this worked fine on desktop but it still didn't animate at all on ios safari.

Comment: did you check the browser compatibility of all the used plugins/librarys?

Comment: yes, it's not really a plugin or library as such, just CSS3

Answer (score 0):

According to the issues of the plugin thats where the problem originates.

Quotes from: https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/issues/472

> Just noticed looking at the my site today that bounceInUp is not
>   working anymore on my iPhone 6 Plus.[...]

---

> I have added ' -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;' to bounceInLeft: 0% {
>   opacity: 0;
>   -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
>   -webkit-transform: translate3d(-3000px, 0, 0); transform: translate3d(-3000px, 0, 0); } and the animation worked.

Formatted code:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;' to bounceInLeft:
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(-3000px, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(-3000px, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: thanks but it's not that issue - the thing i'm talking about affects all the animations, not just bounceInLeft. I think it's to do with any keyframe css animations (just verifying that now)